# sqlcmd '-U sa' unexpected argument

Tags: sql-server, windows, cmd, batch

Estoy intentando ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado desde la consola de comandos de windows con "sqlcmd", y me arroja el mensaje mencionado en el titulo.

adjunto el script que intento ejecutar

```
sqlcmd -S ***.***.***.***\SQLEXPRESS -U sa -P ******** -Q "exec sp_rpt_cencosud_primera_gestion_0005 '20191001','20191015';" -o "C:\Reporte_Primera_Gestion_SAE_20191015.csv"
Sqlcmd: '-U sa': Unexpected argument. Enter '-?' for help.
```

Comment: te falta la base de datos -d dBname

Comment: Yo lo he probado y funciona correctamente si le añades el -d BaseDeDatos

Comment: ya he probado con el argumento "-d", y me arroja exactamente el mismo error